# How would one create a Clojure Lint?

Tags: compiler-construction, clojure, lint

One example of a common Clojure programming error is expecting a lazy expression to be evaluated for side-effects. On the surface it appears checking for unused lazy expressions would be helpful. What would be the best approach to identifying this and other [common mistakes](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/245ed3cb5523aea2/2f2b94f2e7d9010a)? Should the core compiler check for these situations, or should it be the domain of a lint program to detect? What would be a good way to start the implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

- Multimethods with no `:default` method
- Missing documentation strings
- In cases where the argument to a function is always the same type, suggesting type hints
  on arguments
- Pointing out multiple copies of identical anonymous functions
- Pointing out tail recursion and suggesting restructuring
- Using a macro where a function would suffice
- Unused arguments, especially `& rest` type arguments
- Where a function will use BigNums
  instead of just ints or floating point

Not sure how these checks would be implemented, but they would sure save me from myself a lot of the time.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas just to get things started; it could detect lazy code that can never be realized, or point out areas where reflection will be used. Though in general is clojure a little young as a language to express a common set of provable mistakes?